# Windows 10 802.1x Connectivity

Tags: networking, windows-8, windows-10, ethernet, 802.1x

I have been connecting to my dorm Ethernet using IEEE 802.1X authentication for some time and since I upgraded to Windows 10, I get "Authentication failed" error almost every time I wake the computer from sleep or even hibernation. Everything works fine when I restart the computer completely.

With the "Authentication failed" error, I replug the cable and then after a few tries it usually works fine.
Anyone knows what is wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you update to Windows 10, it will install by default Microsoft drivers for your Ethernet card. That's why you are getting Authentication failed error or frequent disconnection.

Uninstall Microsoft drivers and install manufacturer drivers. It will work